# Quando usar o LiveData ou quando usar o RxJava (ou RxJava2 / RxKotlin)?

Tags: android, kotlin, rxjava

Depois que o `LiveData` foi introduzido como [componente de arquitetura do JetPack](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture), eu vi muita discussão sobre o uso dele. O mais comum é que ele seja usado na camada `viewmodel` do **MVVM**, padrão recomendado pelo [guia arquitetural do Android](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide?hl=pt-pt).

Eu sei que o `LiveData` está preparado para lidar com o ciclo de vida da aplicação, seja de uma **activity**, um **fragment** ou um **serviço**. E também sei que o universo de recursos do `livedata` é muito menor do que o `RxJava`. Também sei que o **Livedata é síncrono e o RxJava é assíncrono**, mas isso pode ser resolvido com as corrotinas no Kotlin.

Muito se fala de usar o `livedata` na camada `viewmodel`, mas eu já vi vários **codelabs** da Google que mostra o uso do `livedata` no repositório e também com o `Room`, por exemplo, veja esses links:

[Usar o LiveData com a Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#use_livedata_with_room)

[Advanced Coroutines with Kotlin Flow and LiveData](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-kotlin-coroutines/index.html#0)

Sendo assim, existe algum motivo prático ou situação pela qual eu devo optar pelo uso do RxJava (ou RxJava2 / RxKotlin) ao invés de usar o LiveData em conjunto com o Corrotinas e outros componentes do JetPack?

Answer (score 0):

O Livedata contém algumas limitações em relação ao RxJava, como por exemplo a falta de manipulação de threads, (O que é resolvido no LiveData com o auxilio de corotines), a grande vantagem por sua vez do LiveData é a inicialização e finalização baseado no ciclo de vida do fragment ou activity.

---

**Curva de aprendizado**

O **RxJava/RxKotlin** requer um tempo maior de aprendizado devido a quantidade de funcionalidades e por oferecer diversas opções.

O **LiveData** depois de ler alguns artigos e aplicar no código, em pouco tempo você já estará utilizando tranquilamente em seus projetos.

Se você esta começando recomendo iniciar pelo LiveData que irá suprir a maior parte das suas necessidades. Agora se quiser um controle maior dos acontecimentos nos apps busque o RxJava.

O importante é compreender que são  tecnologias diferentes e seu uso depende única e exclusivamente do seu conforto em usa-las.

Fontes:

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/livedatareactivestreams-where-rxjava-meets-livedata/

https://medium.com/@s4y.solutions/android-livedata-vs-rxjava-b7fd4e166f24

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51665564/livedata-vs-rxjava

Answer (score -1):

O motivo pelo qual voce viu o uso de liveData sendo utilizado juntamente com ViewModel, é porque é fortemente recomendado o uso de um ViewModel para preparar os dados a serem exibidos em um View, essa View por si não deve gestir nada, só exibir os dados passados do ViewModel e um dos melhores modos de fazer esse link é através do uso de LiveData, onde o ViewModel pega os resultados obtidos da fonte(através do repository por exemplo consumindo um web service ou um db) e coloca em um LiveData. 
A View que apenas sabe exibir os dados observa esse LiveData que quando atualizado automaticamente atualizara o valor da View. Para isso funcionar mais fluidamente uso de viewBinding te permite passar o ViewModel direto ao xml e voce pode declarar diretamente no xml qual liveData cada componente deve receber o dado. (Reactive UI)

Nesse caso ainda, a parte do ViewModel -> Repository voce pode estar usando por exemplo RxKotlin/RxJava.

https://medium.com/kayvan-kaseb/using-android-livedata-2efe44339c05